# Traefik generating host rules for docker containers with multiple domains

Tags: docker, docker-compose, traefik

I really like the way traefik generates hostnames for docker containers I am running locally via docker-compose like

`Host:couchdb.myproject.127.0.0.1.nip.io`

is there a way to make it generate multiple host names?

in my case I would need two: `Host:couchdb.myproject.127.0.0.1.nip.io` and `Host:couchdb.myproject.10.0.2.2.nip.io` to make it accessible from the Android emulator

Comment: For now, it's not possible.